# Get Calendar data in power-bi using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, powerbi

In our organization, we use Office 365. I am doing a POC using Microsoft Graph API and would like to use all employees calendars data to visualize capacity in Power BI.

I have gone through the Graph API document and then I got to know that to get calendar data in Power BI, I need to use the below URL.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[email]/calendar/events
```

But when I try to retrieve calendar data using ODATA feed, it was giving me an error as

> access to the resource is forbidden

Can someone please guide me how can I get the required permissions to access calendar data in Power BI.

Comment: Microsoft Graph is an API, not a pure data feed. You need something in between the Graph and PBI to handle converting your API calls into a usable feed. Have you looked at setting up a [PBI gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-getting-started)?

Comment: I would use the built-in connector to Microsoft Exchange Online.  The authentication is already handled.

Comment: @Marc LaFleur Yes, I have installed gateway in my system and using it.
Can you please suggest me how can gateway, can help to get use Grpah API.